# Globe trotting Grandpa. Where is he going next?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Grandpa was busy finishing up his travel itinerary.

"Where are you going Grandpa?" I asked

"Many places! I want to visit places that are charming, historical--"

"Wow" My reaction

"exciting, sunny, special--" he continued.

"Ok, ok. Where are you going?"

> Flashing a list of places in his hand, he said, " Figure it out
>   yourself"
>
> " I am starting my trip from Africa late summer, not before.
>
> My next stop : Red Cross, Int. Atomic Energy Agency, UNICEF
>
> Then to the land of beautiful mausoleums!" He finally stopped.
>
> " And then?" I asked looking at his list.
>
> "You figure that out son. I will end it on Thanksgiving"
>
> " And son, yes there is a method to my travel plan!" He muttered.

I was looking at his list. Is there a method to his madness?

What places is he visiting? Why?

[image]

Comment: Are the nonstandard spellings (Canbera, Khatmandu, Stockhom) deliberate?

Comment: No they are not. Grandpa's spelling, handwritten.

Comment: Gareth. Grandpa corrected it and said thanks

Comment: Tegicigalpa and Gabarone are still there

Answer (score 13, accepted):

He is visiting

> Nairobi, Kenya; Oslo, Norway; New Delhi, India; Athens, Greece; Tegucigalpa, Honduras; and Ankara, Turkey.

Explanations for clued places:

> Kenya is in Africa. Oslo is where the Nobel Peace Prize is awarded, which the three listed organizations all have won. India is known for mausoleums, including the Taj Mahal. The last stop in Turkey references the popular Thanksgiving bird.

Method of travel:

> The places form a knight's path, and the initials of the countries spell **KNIGHT**.
>  [image: KNIGHT]

Comment: This answer seems to line up with the hint that Grandpa gave - rot13(jvgu gur vavgvnyf bs "punezvat, uvfgbevpny...rkpvgvat, fhaal, fcrpvny" fcryyvat PURFF)

Comment: @noedne. Why not start in  Botswana? Cant you spell BISHOP also?

Comment: @DEEM My best guess is that it has something to do with the fact that Kenya is partially in the Northern Hemisphere and Botswana is in the Southern Hemisphere. This doesn't seem to work, however, as the two countries still have similar summer months.

Comment: You have nicely figured out everything else. There is a clue in the puzzle that rejects Botswana

Comment: Isn't the "Thanksgiving" clue the reason to reject BISHOP? There would be no reason to end on Panama that's related to Thanksgiving